# When calling super().__init__ how can I tell if the super init is object.__init__ in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an arbitrary class inheritance
how do I find out if `super().__init__ == object.__init__`?

#### Description + Example

I have this code that I'm not allowed to touch which defines classes A, B, C, CombinedCba, CombinedAc and each class has this weird `__init__` constraint which validates instance properties.
When init calls are made in all base classes, we get the error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

So to prevent that error, we should stop calling super init when it is object init.
I am able to edit the super_init function. How do I detect when super init is init? If I know that I can not make the next super init call and eliminate the error.

```
# code that I can edit
def super_init(self, super_instance, *args, **kwargs):
  # checking super_instance.__init__ == object.__init__ OR super_instance.__init__ is object.__init__ doesn't work
  # pseudo-code
  if super_instance.__init__ is not object.__init__:
    super_instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# auto generated code is from here on down
class A:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.a = kwargs['a']
    assert self.a == 'a'
    super_init(self, super(), *args, **kwargs)

class B:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.b = kwargs['b']
    self.some_num = kwargs['some_num']
    assert self.some_num <= 30
    super_init(self, super(), *args, **kwargs)

class C:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.some_num = kwargs['some_num']
    assert self.some_num >= 10
    super_init(self, super(), *args, **kwargs)

class CombinedCba(C, B, A):
  pass

combo_cba = CombinedCba(a='a', b='b', some_num=25)


class CombinedAc(A, C):
  pass

combo_ac = CombinedAc(a='a', some_num=15)
```

Comment: It might be worth giving some context why you feel the need to do so. If an ``__init__`` ends up with arguments that no-one needed and no-one to pass them on to, that usually indicates a bug or design flaw.

Comment: Thank you. I added the context about why this is needed for my use case.

Comment: `MyClass.__base__ is object`?  or `MyClass.__bases__[0] is object`

Comment: Each of the classes A, B, C has object in its bases, right? As the last (-1 index) entry in mro? Are you suggesting that we check the remaining classes in `self.__class__.__mro__` and stop if object is the only one remaining?

Comment: Note using `Class` instead of `class` means that this isn't runnable code.

Comment: ...part of why I point that out is that it would be helpful to describe, in the "why I need this" section, what error you get if you _don't_ implement this logic, so someone else can try to find a different way to avoid that error.

Comment: Thank you; fixed that typo. It is now `class`

Comment: (which is to say, this smells to me much like an XY problem; "I'm asking how to do Y because I think it's the best way to solve problem X", without letting folks know it's problem X you're trying to solve).

Comment: ...the practices described in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/, introducing the modern `super()` implementation, don't to my knowledge describe the need for any workaround of this type.

Comment: (the question _does_ describe the problem you get if you don't use `super()`, but if it contains an effort to explain the problem you get using `super()` without a workaround of the type described, I'm missing it).

Comment: Thanks, I added that missing info to the "why I need this". Higher level init invocations are needed to run class specific validation code.

Comment: `but if it contains an effort to explain the problem you get using super()`
Thank you, I added the error that happens if we don't stop before calling object init.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217663/discussion-between-spacether-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Each argument should be "owned" by a single class. The fact that `B` and `C` both depend on `some_num` is a design flaw.

Comment: So these classes are produced from components from an openapi spec. Per the openapi specification, constraints are additional and may be overlapping. So two or more classes can own and constrain the same name property. These specs are produced by the end user so they may structure constraints and base class inheritance however they want. This is a requirement, not a design flaw :)
Per the spec we are required to support applying constraints from multiple classes at the same time, even if they are overlapping.

Comment: If you can't change how `B` and `C` work, then you can't inherit from them directly. You'll need to define wrappers that correctly handle `some_num` already being present on the object, rather than being passed to `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I was able to get this so work was to build a new temporary class
containing the remaining super classes, then checking the `__init__` method of that class.

```
def super_init(self, super_instance, *args, **kwargs):
    classes_in_order = self.__class__.__mro__
    for i, cls in enumerate(classes_in_order):
        if cls == super_instance.__thisclass__:
            remainder_cls = type('_unused', classes_in_order[i+1:], {})
    super_init_is_object_init = remainder_cls.__init__ == object.__init__
    if not super_init_is_object_init:
        super_instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

These attempts didn't work:

- checking `super().__init__ == object.__init__` did not work
- checking `super().__init__ is object.__init__` did not work
- checking `super(super().__thisclass__, self)` vs `object.__init__` did not work
- introspecting the function signatures with `inspect.signature` did not work

Comment: can you edit the above details in the question itself?

Comment: Which details specifically? This is a solution so doesn't it make sense to keep it separate?

Comment: this is the solution working for you, what I suggest is add the solution in the problem statement and then people with the other solution will add there solution in answer section

Comment: Any number of solutions can be added right now. In my opinion this one should be in the running also. Self answering questions is fine here per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

First, define `A`, `B`, and `C` to use `super` correctly:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        assert a == 'a'
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, some_num, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b
        self.some_num = some_num
        assert self.some_num <= 30

class C:
    def __init__(self, some_num, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.some_num = some_num
        assert self.some_num >= 10
```

In particular, note that both `B` and `C` claim "ownership" of `some_num`, without worrying yet that another class might make use of it.

Next, define a mix-in class that does nothing but ensure that `some_num` is used to set the `some_num` attribute.

```
class SomeNumAdaptor:
    def __init__(self, some_num, **kwargs):
        self.some_num = some_num
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Third, define wrappers for `B` and `C` that get the value of `some_num` from `self` in order to add it back as a keyword argument (which `SomeNumAdaptor` stripped):

```
class CWrapper(C):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(some_num=self.some_num, **kwargs)

class BWrapper(B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(some_num=self.some_num, **kwargs)
```

This means that both `B` and `C` will "reset" the value of `self.num`.

(A wrapper isn't necessary if you can also modify `B` and `C` to make `some_num` optional and check for the existence of `self.some_num`.)

Finally, define your combination classes in terms of `SomeNumAdaptor` and the wrapper classes. You must inherit from `SomeNumAdaptor` *first*, to ensure that `BWrapper` and `CWrapper` find `some_num` as an attribute, regardless of their relative ordering.

```
class CombinedAbc(SomeNumAdaptor, A, BWrapper, CWrapper):
    pass


class CombinedCba(SomeNumAdaptor, CWrapper, BWrapper, A):
    pass

combo_cba = CombinedCba(a='a', b='b', some_num=25)
combo_abc = CombinedAbc(a='a', b='b', some_num=15)
```

---

The above all assume that neither `B` nor `C` store a modified value of its `some_num` argument to the attribute. If it does, you'll need more complicated wrappers to handle it, likely doing more than simply passing the received value to `__init__`. Note that this could indicate a more fundamental issue with inheriting from both `B` and `C` at the same time.

Comment: I belatedly noticed that you can't modify `A` et al. Consider requesting that they not be generated in such an unorthodox way.